# SELECT a date that is greater than current date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database table where a single cell contains multiple dates and I am wanting to SELECT all rows that contain a cell where one or more of the dates is greater than todays date is this possible? (using PHP)

Comment: When you say cell you mean a column? so in one single column you have many dates? are they comma separated?

Comment: the field is a simple text field (this is my first project using MySQL and PHP so I accept it may not be the best way to store and use my data) the table is used to store events which may only occur on one date or occasionally many dates, past events are irrelevant so I only want to pull the row where the date field(set as a text field at the minute) contains a date that is in the future of 'today's' date...

Comment: The data is not currently comma separated but it is only test data and easily formatted...

Comment: The best thing would be to create another table only for dates with a relationship to the original table, one to many, in that way you will be able to have one row in the original table related to many date columns on the new table.

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
select * from MyTable where MyDate > Now()
```

How does your single field contain multiple dates? Maybe you should consider a separate table for this instead.

Comment: From your example, I think MyDate has many dates inside according to @Michael Jones, that wont work.

Comment: You're right... I'm not sure how you can have many dates in a single field, at least not in MySql. PostgreSQL on the other hand allows horrors such as array date times.

Comment: the dates are currently stored in a 'text' field see comment on original post thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the field is a `DATE` or `DATETIME` you can use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datefield > NOW()
```

Answer (score 1):

A "single cell contains multiple dates" .. is the crux of the problem. Here are three options.

#### Normalize/fix the schema

Start with an adequately normalized schema - in particular, any column/"cell" can have at most *one* date (or piece of information). This may or may not require introducing another table depending upon the role of the information.

This approach is scalable and works within the RDMBS/RA design and, if done, the other queries presented would "just work".

(This is by far the overall best option and should be done if at all possible. Proper normalization should also guide further schema development to mitigate such issues in the future.)

#### Create a normalized view

Create a normalized view of the denormalized table (or such a nomalizing query) that can be `JOIN`ed. Then use one the various suggested answers (that work on a normalized schema) .. albeit at an extreme disadvantage of not being able to utilize indices.

This is terribly messy, but it can be done. See [SELECT de-normalized columns into separate records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250280/select-de-normalized-columns-into-separate-records) for an example. (Note the synthesized row relationship here, although some [non MySQL] databases also support table-valued functions and cross applications of such.)

This approach does not scale because it cannot use indices.

#### Filter in client (PHP)

Fetch every row. Loop and use `explode`, etc, as appropriate.

This approach does not scale due to lack of indices *and* requiring all the data is fetched locally.

---

While finding equal values in denormalized columns can be done with various hacks (e.g. `FIND_IN_SET`), finding relative (i.e. larger/smaller) values is not possible with the same techniques. The solution that works in both cases is to *fix* the underlying schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only after a `DATE` and not a `DATETIME` you can use `CURDATE()` instead of `NOW()`